# how to show real-time data using node.js, socket.io and mysql?

Tags: mysql, node.js, socket.io

I am new to Node.js and trying to show real-time data to a web-page. What I try to do is first I insert into MySQL database via an URL. This is URL [http://localhost:4000/api/motor_details?deviceId=145&a=sdfa3&b=us&c=uds]. Below code is able to insert into the database. The data is visible only refreshing the page but I want to see inserted data to my web-page without refreshing it.
This is my index.js (Main File)

```
<pre>
var express = require('express');
    var socket = require('socket.io');
    var mysql = require('mysql');
    var http = require("http");
    var app = express();
    var server = app.listen(4000,function(){
        console.log('Listening 4000');
    });
    var io = socket(server);
    app.use(express.static('public'));

    var connectSql = mysql.createConnection({
        host: "localhost",
        user: "root",
        password: "root",
        database: "grid_component",
        socketPath: '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock'
    });
    connectSql.connect();
    app.get('/api/motor_details', function(req, res) {
        var device_id = req.param('deviceId');
        var a = req.param('a');
        var b = req.param('b');  
        var c = req.param('c');  
        var entries = {
            device_id: device_id,
            a: a,
            b: b,
            c: c,
            date: '2018-06-27'
        }
        var query = connectSql.query('insert into entries set ?', entries,function (err, result) {
            if(err){
                console.error(err);
                return;
            }  
        })
    });
    io.on('connection',function(socket){
        connectSql.query('SELECT * FROM entries',function(err,rows){
            if(err) throw err;
            socket.emit('showrows', rows);
        });
    });
</pre>

<pre>
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:4000');
 socket.emit('showrows');
 socket.on('showrows', function(rows) {
     var html='';
     for(var i=0; i<rows.length; i++){
         html += rows[i].device_id + ' ' + rows[i].a + '<br>';
     }  
     document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = html;
 }); 
</pre>

[![Error Screenshot][1]][1]
```

I even tried to change the req.param with req.params, req.body or req.query but its showed undefined

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using a query string for parameters [http://localhost:4000/api/motor_details?deviceId=145&a=sdfa3&b=us&c=uds] instead of route based parameters [http://localhost:4000/api/motor_details/145/sdfa3/us/uds], you should use req.query instead of req.params or req.route.

In Express 4+, you will want to use req.query.name-of-parameter instead of req.query('deviceId')
https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.query

After getting data into the database, you will want to emit an event through socket.io from your node server to your client web page to tell it to retrieve the data.

```
var express = require('express');
var socket = require('socket.io');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var http = require("http");
var app = express();
var server = app.listen(4000,function(){
    console.log('Listening 4000');
});
var io = socket(server);
app.use(express.static('public'));

var connectSql = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "root",
    database: "grid_component",
    socketPath: '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock'
});
connectSql.connect();
app.get('/api/motor_details', function(req, res) {
    var device_id = req.query.deviceId;
    var a = req.query.a;
    var b = req.query.b;  
    var c = req.query.c;  
    var entries = {
        device_id: device_id,
        a: a,
        b: b,
        c: c,
        date: '2018-06-27'
    }
    var query = connectSql.query('insert into entries set ?', entries,function (err, result) {
        if(err){
            console.error(err);
            return;
        }  
    })
    //emit using socket io, you can name it whatever you want
    socket.emit('sendingMessage');
});

//set up route to retrieve motor details
app.get('/api/get-motor-details', function(req, res) {

    var query = connectSql.query('SELECT * FROM entries',function(err,rows){
        if(err) throw err;
        res.end(JSON.stringify(rows);
    });
});

//all this is doing is telling the server to retrieve the data upon every socket connection, which is not the behavior you wanted
/*io.on('connection',function(socket){
    connectSql.query('SELECT * FROM entries',function(err,rows){
        if(err) throw err;
        socket.emit('showrows', rows);
    });
});*/


//-----------------CLIENT--------------------------
/*on your client webpage you will need to set up socket.io and a listener for 
the sendingMessage event*/
var socket = io('http://localhost:4000');
socket.on('sendingMessage', () => {
    //use whatever library you want for ajax calls, this is just an example
    fetch('http://localhost:4000/api/get-motor-details')
    .then((response) => {
        var html='';
        for(var i=0; i<response.length; i++){
            html += response[i].device_id + ' ' + response[i].a + '<br>';
        }  
        document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = html;
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But if I am trying to run an URL. it throws me an error. [Cannot GET /api/motor_details/145/sdfa3/us/uds].

Comment: see, Inserting data into the database is not a problem. I want inserted data to be reflected on web-page without refreshing the page.

Comment: Do not use /api/motor_details/145/sdfa3/us/uds as your URL. I was just giving an example for what route based URL's look like. Use the URL you were using from the start. I did edit my answer, so please take a look. You need to send an event with socket.io right after you insert into the database. Then, you need an event listener on the client that will retrieve the motor details when the socket message is sent on the server. You also need a route for retrieving the details, which I included.

Comment: I tried that already. It throws me an error that socket.emit is not defined. what could be the reason?

Comment: As i can understand, i need to make it global but don't know how

Comment: Do you get this error on the server or the client? What is your latest code?

Comment: This error is from the server side. The code which you edited that's the same code. I didn't do any change in it.